# Proof by contradiction to show that if $x^2 +2x-3=0$ then $x\neq 2$

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I need to write a proof by contradiction to show that if $x^2 +2x-3=0$ then $x\neq 2$

To do a proof by contradiction, you assume the opposite. So I would assume that if $x^2+2x-2$ is not equal to $0$, then $x=2$.

To prove:
Assume $x^2+2x-2$ is not equal to $0$ for $x$ in $E$....

Comment: What you say is *not* a proof by contradiction but a logical mistake: you want to prove $\,A\implies B\,$ by means of $\,\neg A\implies \neg B\;$ , which is wrong. What you can do is the counterpositive $\,\neg B\implies \neg A\;$ ...

Answer (score 8):

First: To prove $\;p\implies q$ using a proof by contradiction, it is not a good idea to think of it as  "assuming the opposite." Assuming the opposite of **what**? In logic as in math, it's good to think of "opposite" of an assertion as its **negation.** And importantly, you need to remember here exactly *which* part of the overall assertion gets "negated" in our assumption:

We have an overall assertion which we call an *implication*, which has the form $\;p \implies q$: $\;p$ happens to also be an assertion (serving as a *premise*, or antecedent, of the implication) which is said to imply another assertion, $q$ (which we call the *conclusion*, or consequent, of the implication.)

Now: To prove $p \implies q$ using a proof by contradiction, you assume the premise $p$, and you also assume the ***negation*** of $q$, that is, you *assume the negation of the conclusion.*

In this case, you start by assuming that the premise $x^2 + 2x - 3 = 0$ is true, and *by assuming* that it is **not** the case that the conclusion "$x \neq 2$" holds(i.e., you assume it is false that $x \neq 2)$. In other words, here, we assume $x^2 + 2x - 3 = 0\;$ **and** suppose $\bf x = 2$. Now the aim is to *arrive at a contradiction*.

.....[Work needed: find the contradiction].....

Then, having found a contradiction, you can conclude that the *assumption* $(x = 2)$ is ***false***, and therefore, it follows that if the premise $x^2 + 2x - 3$ is true, then the conclusion $\lnot (x = 2) \iff \;x \neq 2$ must also be true.

Comment: so to find the contradiction, I would do (x^2) +2x -2=0 for x+2.  Then (2^2) + 2(2)-2=0 which is not true.   Is this correct?

Comment: oops, I think you mean $-3$ in the equation. But yes, Exactly! substitute, as you did, evaluate, and Then you can **reject** the "supposition that $x = 2$" and claim that if $x^2 + 2x - 3 = 0$, then $x\neq 2$.

Comment: In either case, if we have $x^2 + 2x - 3 = 0$ or $x^2 + 2x - 2 =0$, you can see that we get a contradiction if we suppose $x = 2.$ In either case, by arriving at a contradiction, you **can** conclude that $x\neq 2$

Comment: This helps so much!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome, sophie!

Comment: If $x=2$, then $x^2+2x-3=4+4-3=5\ne0$. By contraposition, if $x^2+2x-3=0$, then $x\ne2$. This is not a proof by contradiction. Of course one can add the hypothesis that $x=2$ and derive a "contradiction"; but I find that this kind of exercise makes more obscure, rather than clearer, the concept of proof by contradiction.

Comment: Assuming $x^2 + 2x - 3$ and $x = 2$, we derive a contradiction, @egreg. I agree that the task lends itself better to a proof by contrapositive, but alas, sometimes students are **assigned** the task of using a particular proof method, in this case, to use proof by contradiction, to prove a statement. And so we have a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @amWhy My comment was about those tasks: they make math look more complicated than it is.

Comment: @egreg I agree entirely! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You took the revese meaning of contradiction.

If you have to prove anything by contradiction it means that the answer which you have to prove is false(x is not equal to 2) and not the statement which you will use to prove the same ($x^2+2x-3=0$).

The basic idea behind contradiction is that you assume that the thing you need to prove is not correct and you $contradict$ yourself by proving that you are wrong, that everything you've assumed is wrong and since you just assume the opposite, the opposite of the opposite i.e. the thing you assumed wrong is correct.

This is an analytical approach to try your questions. If there is a general statement $\mathbb x$ and from it you have to prove statement $\mathbb a$ then you take the converse of it {$\mathbb b$} to do the job. You put your assumption back to $\mathbb x$ and if it follows then your answer is $\mathbb b$ else it is $\mathbb a$.

So here,
$$x^2+2x-3=0$$
We assume$x=2$.
So we get $5=0$.
So our assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to prove a logical proposition by contradiction, you have to assume the opposite. In your case $p\Longrightarrow q$ is false only when $p$ is true and $q$ is false, translating this to your problem:

If $x^2+2x-3=0$, then $x\neq 2$.

We assume $p$ is true: $x^2+2x-3=0$.

And $q$ is false: $x=2$.

Are those two things compatible, can you see the contradiction here?

Answer (score 0):

You were probably thrown by the ridiculously easy nature of the answer, which is this:

If $x$ were equal to $2$, then $x^2+2x-3$ would equal $5$, not $0$.

Hence (duh!) $x$ is not equal to $2$.